# Plotly Bubble chart from pandas crosstab

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, crosstab

How can I plot a bubble chart from a dataframe that has been created from a pandas crosstab of another dataframe?

Imports;

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
```

The crosstab was created using;

```
df = pd.crosstab(raw_data['Speed'], raw_data['Height'].fillna('n/a'))
```

The df contains mostly zeros, however where a number appears I want a point where the value controls the point size. I want to set the Index values as the x axis and the columns name values as the Y axis.

The df would look something like;

```
         10    20    30    40    50
1000     0     0    0      0     5
1100     0     0    0      7     0
1200     1     0    3      0     0
1300     0     0    0      0     0
1400     5     0    0      0     0
```

I’ve tried using scatter & Scatter like this;

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index.values, y=df.columns.values, size=df.values,
                         mode='lines'),
              row=1, col=3)
```

This returned a TypeError: 'Module' object not callable.

Any help is really appreciatted. Thanks

**UPDATE**

The answers below are close to what I ended up with, main difference being that I reference 'Speed' in the melt line;

```
df.reset_index()
df.melt(id_vars="Speed")
df.rename(columns={"index":"Engine Speed",
                    "variable":"Height",
                    "value":"Count"})
df[df!=0].dropna()

scale=1000

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["Speed"], y=df["Height"],mode='markers',marker_size=df["Count"]/scale),
              row=1, col=3)
```

This works however my main problem now is that the dataset is huge and plotly is really struggling to deal with it.

**Update 2**

Using Scattergl allows Plotly to deal with the large dataset very well!

Comment: Can you show us the whole traceback?

Comment: @Pygirl Updated with traceback.. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is go.scatter? Could you include what import statement you are using?

Comment: Do you mind to share `raw`?

Comment: @Erik, Updated with Imports - I'm using Plotly

Comment: @rpanai I'm sorry but I can't

Comment: So you could try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @rpanai The raw_data is not relevant to the question.. The data that is important is 'df', which I have created an example for. I have the data I need, the problem I am having is that I cannot plot it the way I would like.

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim try to change `df[df!=0]` for `df = df[df["Count"]!=0],reset_index(drop=True)`. Even if you can't see the point where count is zero that is added to the trace.

Comment: This improves things slightly but its still very laggy, I have around 50,000 rows in the df. I'll try to remove hover data and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the case you can use `plotly.express` this is very similar to @Erik answer but *shouldn't* return errors.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from io import StringIO

txt = """
        10    20    30    40    50
1000     0     0    0      0     5
1100     0     0    0      7     0
1200     1     0    3      0     0
1300     0     0    0      0     0
1400     5     0    0      0     0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

df = df.reset_index()\
       .melt(id_vars="index")\
       .rename(columns={"index":"Speed",
                        "variable":"Height",
                        "value":"Count"})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Speed", y="Height",size="Count")
fig.show()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
In case you got error please check your `pandas version` with `pd.__version__` and try to check line by line this

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

df = df.reset_index()

df = df.melt(id_vars="index")

df = df.rename(columns={"index":"Speed",
                        "variable":"Height",
                        "value":"Count"})
```

and report in which line it breaks.

Comment: Which version of `pandas` or `plotly` are you using?

Comment: Plotly = 4.5.1
Pandas = 1.0.1

Comment: df = df.melt(id_vars="index")

Comment: do you mind to show what `df.reset_index().columns` returns to you? In my case I get `Index(['index', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Updated the question, thanks for the help! Although, plotly is struggling to deal with the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [tidy format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) to represent your data. We say a dataframe is tidy if and only if

1. Each row is an observation
2. Each column is a variable
3. Each value must have its own cell

To create a more tidy-dataframe you can do

```py
df = pd.crosstab(raw_data["Speed"], raw_data["Height"])
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df.melt(id_vars=["Speed", "Height"], value_vars=["Counts"])
```

```
   Speed  Height  Counts
0   1000      10       2
1   1100      20       1
2   1200      10       1
3   1200      30       1
4   1300      40       1
5   1400      50       1
```

The next step is to do the actual plotting.

```py
# when scale is increased bubbles will become larger
scale = 10 
# create the scatter plot
scatter = go.Scatter(
    x=df.Speed, 
    y=df.Height,
    marker_size=df.counts*scale,
    mode='markers')
fig = go.Figure(scatter)
fig.show()
```

This will create a plot as shown below.
[image: bubble plot]

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, the format you describe is much easier to work with. I tried this, but I recieved an error stating that 'Height' was not a variable listed in 'df'.. Could this be due to the way I used crosstab earlier in the code?

Comment: Go tidy is the way to do this unless one wants to deal with multiple traces. You should fix your first codeblock cos it returns error. And `level=0` in `reset_index` is superfluous.

Comment: Reviewing the answer again, this doesn't do what I need. The plot should show like how @rpanai has done it, although I get errors here too.